# Why is E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y), but E(XY) ≠ E(X)E(Y)?

Tags: probability

Can somemone explain in simple terms why it is like that?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Because $E$ is an expectation and not a field isomorphism.

Comment: Why is $(1)(1)=1$ but $1+1\neq 1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Okay, sorry, wont happen again

Comment: It would help to give a reference of where you saw that E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y), and then ask what in that reference is unclear. Also, why do you think E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)?

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is a linear map, so given $X,Y$ two random variables, $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y).$
On the other hands, we have that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ if $X,Y$ are two random variables that are also uncorrelated. Note that indipendence implies uncorrelation.